# Localization for input field with double value in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, localization, razor-pages

In my ViewModel I have a property like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]        
public double SomeDoubleProperty { get; set; }
```

Markup:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="ViewModel.SomeDoubleProperty" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">
        @Localizer[nameof(Model.ViewModel.SomeDoubleProperty)]
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
            </div>
            <input asp-for="ViewModel.SomeDoubleProperty"
                   class="form-control">
        </div>
        <span asp-validation-for="ViewModel.SomeDoubleProperty" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

After loading the page (with the default value 0) it is shown like this in the input field:

[image]

(The current culture and current ui culture of the thread is "de", so the decimal separator "," is the expected one).

But when I now leave the input field, the following validation error is shown:

> The field SomeDoubleProperty must be a number.

When replacing the "," with a ".", the validator accepts the value.
How can I achieve that the "," is accepted, too, if the current ui culture is "de"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to download and configure client side validation scripts:

- cldrjs
- cldr-data
- globalizejs

in the root of your project create a new file name it "libman.json" and add the below libraries to it:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "jsdelivr",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "library": "cldrjs@0.5.1",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/cldr"
    },
    {
      "library": "cldr-data@35.1.0",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/cldr-data"
    },
    {
      "library": "globalize@1.4.2",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/globalize"
    }
  ]
}
```

When you save the file it will download all scripts to the wwwroor/lib folder.

Then open `wwwroot/lib/cldr-data/package.json` and add the below lines to the end of the page before the closing braket:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "cldr-data": ">=26"
  }
```

When you save the file it will download all json data (numbering, date, time, currency, etc.) for all cultures. The download may take a while (~35MB).

There is one more js library "jquery.validate.globalize.min.js" needs to be installed but the version in jsdelivr 0.1.1 is not compatible, we need v1.0, so either download it manually from [GitHub](https://github.com/johnnyreilly/jquery-validation-globalize) or just use the jsdelivr's import functionality from GitHub as below:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/johnnyreilly/jquery-validation-globalize@1.0.0/jquery.validate.globalize.min.js"></script>
```

Then create a new partial view name it "_LocalizationValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml" and add the libraries to it:

```
<!-- cldr scripts (needed for globalize) -->
<script src="/lib/cldr/dist/cldr.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/cldr/dist/cldr/event.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/cldr/dist/cldr/supplemental.min.js"></script>

<!-- globalize scripts -->
<script src="/lib/globalize/dist/globalize.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/globalize/dist/globalize/number.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/globalize/dist/globalize/date.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/globalize/dist/globalize/currency.min.js"></script>

<!-- this file can be downloaded from : -->
<!-- https://github.com/johnnyreilly/jquery-validation-globalize -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/johnnyreilly/jquery-validation-globalize@1.0.0/jquery.validate.globalize.min.js"></script>

<!-- code to get check if current cultures scripts are exists -->
<!-- if not, select parent cultures scripts -->
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment
@{
    string GetDefaultLocale()
    {
        const string localePattern = "lib\\cldr-data\\main\\{0}";
        var currentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        var cultureToUse = "en"; //Default regionalisation to use

        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, string.Format(localePattern, currentCulture.Name))))
            cultureToUse = currentCulture.Name;
        else if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, string.Format(localePattern, currentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName))))
            cultureToUse = currentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

        return cultureToUse;
    }
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var culture = "@GetDefaultLocale()";
    $.when(
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/main/" + culture + "numbers.json"),
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/main/" + culture + "/currencies.json"),
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/supplemental/numberingSystems.json"),
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/main/" + culture + "/ca-gregorian.json"),
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/main/" + culture + "/timeZoneNames.json"),
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/supplemental/timeData.json"),
        $.get("/lib/cldr-data/supplemental/weekData.json"),
    ).then(function () {
        // Normalize $.get results, we only need the JSON, not the request statuses.
        return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
            return result[0];
        });
    }).then(Globalize.load).then(function () {
        Globalize.locale(culture);
    });
</script>
```

Last, just include this partial view after the default _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml where you need the localization validation to be done.

```
<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml" />
<partial name="_LocalizationValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml" />
```

### Alternate method

I created a TagHelperComponent to avoid all the hard work, you even don't need to download the scripts to your local.

- install the nuget package:

```cs
Install-Package LazZiya.TagHelpers -Version 2.1.0
```

- add LazZiya.TagHelpers to _ViewImports :

```
@using LazZiya.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, LazZiya.TagHelpers
```

- register the localization validation tag helper component in startup:

```cs
services.AddTransient<ITagHelperComponent, LocalizationValidationScriptsTagHelperComponent>();
```

- add the tag to the scripts section of the page for validating localized input fields (the default _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml must be loaded as well):

```
<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml" />
<localization-validation-scripts></localization-validation-scripts>
```

This TagHelper will automatically detect the current culture name and add all necessary scripts for validating localized values.

For more details see [LazZiya.TagHelpers](http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/27-LazZiya_TagHelpers)

Comment: Your Nuget package works, thanks a lot! The only thing that does not work now is the re-formatting of the input value -> Id should be change to the defined format ("{0:0.00}"). Any idea how to achieve this without losing the localized comma separator?

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) re the formatting issue, you can define localized formatting string depending on the culture. Just create a resource file with public access modifiers then add format string for each culture then just use in the attribute [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = MyResource.DecimalFormat, ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

Comment: btw, I didn't try the localization of the formatting but I think it should work

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work. I have another double property with the dataformatstring {0:N0} which should work for all cultures but when leaving the input field the value does not get formatted again.

Comment: what didn't work exactly with the formatting? I just tried it and everything worked fine with "{0:0.00}" and "{0:N0}" for both cultures and I didn't use any resources for culture specific formatting

Comment: The formatting works fine when loading the page with the initial values. But after typing e. g. 12345567 into the input field with the "{0:N0}" format and I leave the field, the value does not change into 123.45.567 as expected.

Comment: well, in this case you need to use input mask like https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/

Comment: Yes, I tried several mask libraries but I haven't found one that deals with the culture dependent format requirements (separators)

Comment: input mask libraries uses a string for the formatting pattern, just use a localized pattern string from a resource file instead of the string

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Laz Ziya I found a combination that does the trick:

ViewModel:

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = "RangeAttribute_ValidationError")]
    public double SomeDoubleProperty { get; set; }
```

Markup:

```
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="ViewModel.SomeDoubleProperty" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">
            @Localizer[nameof(Model.ViewModel.SomeDoubleProperty)]
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
                </div>
                <input asp-for="ViewModel.SomeDoubleProperty"
                       class="form-control"
                       id="some-double-input" digit-count="2">
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="ViewModel.SomeDoubleProperty" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<partial name="_NumberInputPartial" />
```

NumberInputPartial:

```
 @using System.Threading;

@*To use this partial add the following attribute to the input element: digit-count="{enter requested digit count here}"*@

<script asp-location="Footer">
    function toLocalizedNumberString(numberAsString, digitCount) {
        var decimalSeparator = '@(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator)';
        var groupSeparator = '@(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator)';
          var num = parseFloat(numberAsString.replace(decimalSeparator, '.'));
          return ( num
            .toFixed(digitCount)
            .replace('.', decimalSeparator)
            .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1' + groupSeparator)
            )
    }
    $("input[digit-count]").on("focusin", function () {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(@("/[" + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator + "]/g"), ""));
    });
    $("input[digit-count]").on("focusout", function () {
        $(this).val(toLocalizedNumberString($(this).val(), $(this).attr("digit-count")));
    });
</script>

<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
<localization-validation-scripts></localization-validation-scripts>
```